# Why does my Ansible module fail with TypeError: 'itertools.imap' object has no attribute

Tags: python, ansible

Given following python code in my Ansible module file

```
def remove_old_plugin_version(data):
    has_changed = False
    glb = os.path.join(os.path.sep,'/opt/sonarqube/sonarque/extensions/plugins/','*.jar') 
    plgns = map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(glb))
    plgn_installed = plgns[0]
```

This code fails on line with `plgn_installed` With message

> TypeError: 'itertools.imap' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I can execute this code just fine when using Python console

```
>>> import glob,os
>>> glb = os.path.join(os.path.sep,'/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/','*.jar') 
>>> plgns = map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(glb))
>>> plgn_installed = plgns[0]
>>> plgn_installed
'sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.2.jar'
>>>
```

Why does this code fail in an Ansible module? How should I code it correctly for Ansible to execute?

As I workaround I am using

```
plgns = []
for plgn in map(os.path.basename, glob.glob(glb)):
    plgns.append(plgn)
plgn_installed = plgns[0]
```

Ansible version is the same in both cases. Python 2.7.15+ I am using Ansible with Vagrant. Vagrant shows

```
sonarqube: Package python-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I start my Python console on the Vagrant node

```
[vagrant@sonarqube ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

Comment: Are you using the same version of python in both cases? Also, if you're on python 3.4+, you can replace this all with pathlib i.e. `plgns = list(Path('/opt/blabla').glob('*.jar')`. Also you might want to guard against there being more than one jar file in the directory.

Comment: Must be that, in Python 2.7 itertools.imap exists, in Python 3.X doesn't, so check your python version

Comment: And indeed `itertools.imap` object has no attribute `__getitem__` under Python 2.7

Comment: Please post a proper [mcve].

Comment: Ansible version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible has code that patches map function on Python2 to behave consistently with Python3, which means to return an iterator.

See for example: [Lamba and Map behaves differently in Ansible 2.2.1.0 #22877](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22877)

> The problem is that we do the following in `ansible.module_utils.basic`:
>
> `from ansible.module_utils.six.moves import map, reduce`
>
> This is effectively doing `from itertools import imap as map`
>
> `imap` works similarly to `map`, however it is an iterator, and does not immediately iterate in your example, so it never expands anything

Note: actual code looks like
`MovedAttribute("map", "itertools", "builtins", "imap", "map")`

In Python3 map returns an iterable, your original code will fail, so using an alternative way is a good idea even if you are still on Python 2